# How to get MainActivity inside a module using AndroidInjector

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

With `dagger-android` one now can simply write the following and successfully inject the app's dependencies:

```
@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {
  @ContributesAndroidInjector
  abstract MainActivity contributesMainActivity();
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
    AndroidInjectionModule.class,
    AppModule.class,
    MainActivityModule.class
})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
  void inject(BaseApplication baseApplication);

  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    Builder application(Application application);

    ApplicationComponent build();
  }
}

@Module
public abstract class AppModule {}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
  HasSupportFragmentInjector {
  @Inject
  DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> dispatchingAndroidInjector;
  @Inject
  Whatever whatever;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  @Override
  public AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
    return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
  }
}


public class BaseApplication extends Application implements 
  HasActivityInjector {
  @Inject
  DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

  @Override
  public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
    return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this);
    super.onCreate();
  }
}

public class Whatever {
   private final FragmentManager fragmentManager;

   @Inject
   Whatever(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.fragmentManager = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
   }
}
```

A very trivial example. Basically wire up everything to be able to get the object `Whatever` with the correct fragment manager injected. This is ok and works.

However, what if I want to use the main activity inside a module? Say I want to actually make `Whatever` explicitly expose the dependency to the fragment manager by changing the constructor argument:

```
@Inject
Whatever(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {...}
```

I now need to provide this dependency. How does one go about it? So I've tried the following:

```
@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {
  @ContributesAndroidInjector
  abstract MainActivity contributesMainActivity();

  @Provides
  static FragmentManager providesFragmentManager(MainActivity activity) {
     return activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
  }
}
```

Now dagger complains that it cannot find a `@Providers` for the `MainActivity`. I thought the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` method would be able to provide the activity. I'm also a bit puzzled as to how it  has no problem injecting the dependency in the first case, but now it cannot do it.

I've also tried to build a factory for this, something like:

```
public FragmentManagerFactory {
   private final FragmentManager fm;

   @Inject
   FragmentManagerFactory(MainActivity mainActivity){
     this.fm = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
   }

   public FragmentManager get() {
     return fm;
   }
}

@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {
  @ContributesAndroidInjector
  abstract MainActivity contributesMainActivity();

  @Provides
  static FragmentManager providesFragmentManager(FragmentManagerFactory fragmentManagerFactory) {
     return fragmentManagerFactory.get();
  }
}
```

Which ends up in the same error.

Has anyone managed to do this?? Before it was pretty easy, one would just build the module with the instance of the `MainActivity` store it in a field and provide that. Now... everything happens behind the curtains.

Would appreciate a lot some help!

Comment: *Before it was pretty easy, one would just build the module with the instance of the MainActivity store it in a field and provide that.*. You can still do it using a `@Subcomponent` for `MainActivity`

Comment: Care to post an example? Feels like it would defeat the purpose of using the ``AndroidInjector``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my setup I have a `di/` package in the root of `sub-di-packages` in my `ui/` package. In the `ui/di` package I have declared the following module and component:

```
@dagger.Module
public class MainActivityModule {
   @Provides
   FragmentManager provideFragmentManager(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    return mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
   }
}
```

*MainActivitySubcomponent*

```
@Subcomponent(modules = MainActivityModule.class)
public interface MainActivitySubcomponent  extends AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity> {
    }
}
```

on the top-level `di` package where I keep my `ApplicationComponent`, I have an additional `module`

```
@Module(subcomponents = {MainActivitySubcomponent.class })
public abstract class BuildersModule {

   @Binds
   @IntoMap
   @ActivityKey(MainActivity.class)
   abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> mainActivityBinder(MainActivitySubcomponent.Builder builder);

}
```

And as you can imagine `BuildersModule`, is part of `@Component(modules = {` of `ApplicationComponent`.

---

Disclaimer: 

<sub><sup>I am fairly new to dagger2 and I am still try to figure out a lot of stuff. There may be better ways to achieve what you need.</sup></sub>

Comment: Cool thanks! And how do you go about injecting the main activity? Do you still use ``AndroidInjector.inject(this)`` or do you build the components manually?

Comment: With `AndroidInjector.inject(this)`. I do have a base class that every injectable Activity extends

Comment: Once again thanks a lot. I've gave it a try, but with this solution I get a run time error when I call ``AndroidInjection.inject(this)`` on the main activity. The exception says that the ``MainActivityModule`` must be set. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Sorry about that, my mistake. I've kept the ``MainActivityModule`` abstract. Thanks a lot!

Comment: simple solution! Awesome